# How to reduce execution time of stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which selects data from listboxes, spinner input box and checkbox it execute perfectly but it take approximately 2.30 minutes for execution which cause to give me an error in my application.

Error is

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Then how can I reduce the time taken by my stored procedure?

This is the stored procedure code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SearchCAMAStructure]
    @section as nvarchar(max),
    @quality as nvarchar(max),
    @style as nvarchar(max),
    @ward as nvarchar(max),
    @improvment as nvarchar(max),
    @condition as nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Declare @Where as varchar(max)
    Declare @Select as varchar(max)

    Set @Select = ' Distinct vi.struct_no as structure, a.assesmt_no as assessment, o.own_last+'' , ''+o.own_first as taxpayer, id.year_built as built, id.effect_age as age, vi.aprais_val as mktvalue
                From [dbo].assessments a
                inner join parcel p on a.parcel_no = p.parcel_no
                inner join valueimp vi on vi.assesmt_no = a.assesmt_no
                inner join owner o on o.id = a.owner_id
                inner join imp_details id on id.improvementId = vi.id and (id.isdeleted is null or id.isdeleted = 0)
                inner join quality_details qd on qd.quality_id = id.quality_id
                inner join section_details sd on sd.section_id = id.section_id
                inner join style_details stdl on stdl.style_id = id.style_id
                inner join parcel pw on p.ward_no = pw.ward_no'


    Set @Where = ' where  sd.section_id =ISNULL(@section,sd.section_id)
     AND qd.quality_id = ISNULL(@quality,qd.quality_id)
     AND stdl.style_id = ISNULL(@style,stdl.style_id )
     AND pw.ward_no = ISNULL(@ward,pw.ward_no )
     AND id.improvementId = ISNULL(@improvment,id.improvementId )'

    if @condition = 1 --Equal to 
    Begin
        Set @Where = @Where + ' and (' +@improvment+ ' is null or id.effect_age = ' +@improvment+ ' )'
    end
    else 
       if @condition = 2 --Greater than or Equal
       Begin
           Set @Where = @Where + 'and (' +@improvment+ ' is null or id.effect_age > ' +@improvment+ ' )'
       end
       else
          if @condition = 3 --Less than or equal
          Begin
              Set @Where = @Where + 'and (' +@improvment+ ' is null or id.effect_age < ' +@improvment+ ' )'
          end

    DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)    

    SET @QUERY= 'Select '+ @SELECT + @WHERE 
    print @QUERY

    EXEC sp_executesql @QUERY , N'@section as nvarchar(max) ,@quality as nvarchar(max),@style as nvarchar(max),@ward as nvarchar(max),@improvment as nvarchar(max)',@section ,@quality,@style,@ward,@improvment
END
```

If I execute the stored procedure in following way it takes to much time for it's execution

```
EXEC usp_SearchCAMAStructure null,null,null,null,null,null
```

Then how to reduce it?

Comment: Why the Oracle tag?

Comment: Don't use Dynamic SQL.  The query engine cannot cache the execution plan.  There is no performance benefit to using this method.

Comment: I would use 3 sub stored procedures and do away with the dynamic sql.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is usually EVIL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace unnecessary `ISNULL()` function from where clause, that may improve performance as well

```
Set @Where = ' where  ( @section IS NULL OR sd.section_id = @section)
 AND (@quality IS NULL OR qd.quality_id = @quality)
 AND (@style IS NULL OR stdl.style_id = @style)
 AND (@ward IS NULL OR pw.ward_no @ward)
 AND (@improvment IS NULL OR id.improvementId = @improvment)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change the dynamic query with the following code..

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_SearchCAMAStructure]    Script Date: 10/18/2016 3:05:14 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SearchCAMAStructure]
@section as nvarchar(max),
@quality as nvarchar(max),
@style as nvarchar(max),
@ward as nvarchar(max),
@improvment as nvarchar(max),
@condition INT
As
Begin

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT  Distinct vi.struct_no as structure, a.assesmt_no as assessment, o.own_last+'' , ''+o.own_first as taxpayer, id.year_built as built, id.effect_age as age, vi.aprais_val as mktvalue
                From [dbo].assessments a
                inner join parcel p on a.parcel_no = p.parcel_no
                inner join valueimp vi on vi.assesmt_no = a.assesmt_no
                inner join owner o on o.id = a.owner_id
                inner join imp_details id on id.improvementId = vi.id and (id.isdeleted is null or id.isdeleted = 0)
                inner join quality_details qd on qd.quality_id = id.quality_id
                inner join section_details sd on sd.section_id = id.section_id
                inner join style_details stdl on stdl.style_id = id.style_id
                inner join parcel pw on p.ward_no = pw.ward_nowhere  sd.section_id =ISNULL(@section,sd.section_id)
     AND qd.quality_id = ISNULL(@quality,qd.quality_id)
     AND stdl.style_id = ISNULL(@style,stdl.style_id )
     AND pw.ward_no = ISNULL(@ward,pw.ward_no )
     AND id.improvementId = ISNULL(@improvment,id.improvementId) 
     AND  ((@condition=1 AND id.effect_age=@improvment) OR (@condition=2 AND id.effect_age>@improvment) OR (@condition=2 AND id.effect_age<@improvment) OR @condition IS NULL )
END
```